# I am unable to find the option 'Site Monitor' while creating jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I installed the jenkins site monitor plugin but I don't see any option in jenkins job. Even it is visible in manage jenkins-> Configure System.

Can someone please help here how to create a site monitor jenkins job , where can I find it while creating job ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it inside the "Add post-build action".